# Update specific ORM object with self object attribute from filtered queryset

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I'm wondering is there any option to update current ORM object from filtered queryset with a new value which comes from current object? Seems bit complicated so maybe I show you an example:

Model looks like:

```
class Car(models.Model):
    car_id = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    initial_value = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    end_value = models.IntegerField(null=True)
```

And some cars in my DB have initial_value but doesn't have an end value, and I want to copy/update the initial_value from specific object to end_value, where end_value is None:

And I know that there exists an ORM formula which update my object with given value in queryset:

```
Car.objects.filter(end_value__isnull=True).update(end_value=100000)
```

But I cannot pass object initial_value to end_value in update method

```
Car.objects.filter(end_value__isnull=True).update(end_value=initial_value) <-- Error
```

Please help, how can I pass object attribute to update attribute? Maybe there is different approach?

Answer (score 1):

You Can use [F-expression](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions)

```
from django.db.models import F
Car.objects.filter(end_value__isnull=True).update(end_value=F('initial_value'))
```

Comment: This is exacly what I needed, thanks so much!